# I'm getting an error with the $\frac$ function and can't seem to figure out what the issue is

Tags: errors, formatting, fractions, nicefrac

I am trying to get a fraction to show up that has multiple terms in the numerator and only one term in the denominator.  I would like the numerator to be "2pi(12,500mi)" and the denominator to be "2pi."  In this case I have spelled out pi because I don't know how to make the symbol on this website but I do know how to do it in LaTeX.  The code I currently have is:

```
C=$\frac{2$\pi$(12,500)}{$\pi$}$\\\
```

When I run this it gives me an error that says:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.46 C=$\frac{2$\pi$(12,500)}{$\pi$}
                                    $\\
?
```

I originally had this set up as a `\nicefrac` with the following code:

```
C=\nicefrac{2$\pi$(12,500)}{$\pi$}\\\
```

This runs fine without any errors but I would like to use the regular `\frac` function because it is neater for the particular problem.  I'm a bit confused as to why this isn't working when it works for `\nicefrac` without issue.  I was under the impression that the general form of `\frac` was `$\frac{numerator}{denominator}$`.  I realize that my numerator is a bit more complicated than just a single number but I can't seem to find the mistake.  If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.  Also this is my first time posting anything here so hopefully the formatting works out.

Comment: You are already in math mode so don't use `$\pi$` but only `\pi`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `$` is used to open and close math-mode, you don't need to use it everywhere. Use `C=$\frac{2\pi(12,500)}{\pi}$`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  Getting rid of the $$ around \pi fixed the problem.  This is my second time using LateX so I'm still getting used to the basics.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik or rather `$C=\frac{2\pi(12,500)}{\pi}$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops. Better indeed :)

Comment: I've seen a lot of MathJax code where `$` is used like an “escape for strange characters to be input with a backslash in front”. This is not how math mode is supposed to behave. The `\nicefrac` command is very misleading in this regard, besides producing very dubious output from the typographic point of view. The whole thing you need is a *single* math formula: `$C=\frac{2\pi(12{,}500}{2\pi}$`. Note also that paragraphs are *not* terminated by ``\\``, but by a blank line; the combination ``\\\`` makes very little sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote,

> I would like the numerator to be `2pi(12,500mi)` and the denominator to be `2pi`.

In addition to not entering and exiting math mode inside a formula, you also need to take care of displaying a number (12500) and its associated units (miles) correctly. To achieve the latter objective, I suggest you use the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package. LaTeX strongly encourages writing formulas in a "high level manner", so that the *meaning* and the specific display choices (use comma as thousands separator? how much space between the number and the units?) are kept separate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx} % use ',' (comma) as thousands separator
\begin{document}
\[  % start display-math mode
C=\frac{2\pi(\SI{12500}{mi})}{2\pi}
\]  % end display-math mode
\end{document}
```